# How to convert SOAP envelope to given envelope using code in an Android

Tags: android, soap

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SoapObject objSaveVisitInfraDetails = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                    PostMETHOD_NAME);
            C = new InfraVisit();
            SoapObject lstInfraVisit = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                    Constant.LstInfraVisit) ;
            objSaveVisitInfraDetails.addProperty("lstInfraVisit",
                    lstInfraVisit);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                objInfraVisit = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                        Constant.InfraVisit);
                objInfraVisit.addProperty("Feedback",
                        "Feedback");
                objInfraVisit.addProperty("Image", null);
                objInfraVisit.addProperty("InfraId", Integer.valueOf(1));
                objInfraVisit.addProperty("ResolveStatus",
                    "ResolveStatus");
                objInfraVisit.addProperty("VisitDetailId",
                        Integer.valueOf(1));
                objInfraVisit.addProperty("Visit_MasterId",
                        Integer.valueOf(1));
                 lstInfraVisit.addProperty("InfraVisit", objInfraVisit)  ;

            }
            objSaveVisitInfraDetails.addProperty("VisitMasterId", 1);
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            Element[] header = new Element[1];
            header[0] = new Element().createElement(null, "Action");
            header[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand", "1");

            header[0].addChild(Node.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE,
                    Constant.NameSpace
                            + "/IInfraService/SaveVisitInfraDetail");
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.headerOut = header;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(objSaveVisitInfraDetails);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(PostSOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.d("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE",
                    androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE222",
                    androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        String  Name = result.getProperty(0).toString();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Errorrr", e.getMessage());


        }
        return null;
    }
```

this is my code from which i am converting soap envalape and post data to server as envalape

my current envalape is :

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header>
<Action mustUnderstand="1">https://softageteledoc.com/IInfraService/SaveVisitInfraDetail</Action>
</v:Header>
<v:Body>
<SaveVisitInfraDetail xmlns="https://softageteledoc.com" id="o0" c:root="1">
<lstInfraVisit i:type="n0:lstInfraVisit" xmlns:n0="https://softageteledoc.com">
<InfraVisit i:type="n0:InfraVisit">
<Feedback i:type="d:string">Feedback</Feedback>
<Image i:null="true" />
<InfraId i:type="d:int">1</InfraId>
<ResolveStatus i:type="d:string">ResolveStatus</ResolveStatus><VisitDetailId i:type="d:int">1</VisitDetailId>
<Visit_MasterId i:type="d:int"></Visit_MasterId></InfraVisit>
</lstInfraVisit>
<VisitMasterId i:type="d:int">1</VisitMasterId>
</SaveVisitInfraDetail>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

and this is my envalape which i have to make so that data will Post easily:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IInfraService/SaveVisitInfraDetail</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SaveVisitInfraDetail xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <lstInfraVisit xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LoopInfra.Contracts.Objects" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:InfraVisit>
          <d4p1:Feedback>Chair Replaced</d4p1:Feedback>
          <d4p1:Image i:nil="true" />
          <d4p1:InfraId>1</d4p1:InfraId>
          <d4p1:ResolveStatus>true</d4p1:ResolveStatus>
          <d4p1:VisitDetailId>1</d4p1:VisitDetailId>
          <d4p1:Visit_MasterId>1</d4p1:Visit_MasterId>
        </d4p1:InfraVisit>
      </lstInfraVisit>
      <VisitMasterId>1</VisitMasterId>
    </SaveVisitInfraDetail>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope
```

This we have to archive I have to convert `envelope` from my current `envelope` to desire envalpe please  help I am using `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar`  for POST data please help